# Spoiler in list hides list number

Tags: bug, design, spoilers, list

While reading [an answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63637/41573) over on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), I noticed that having a spoiler in a list hides the item number/bullet. I can demonstrate it here. *(It seems to be an issue only in Chrome.)*

**Ordered lists.**

1. > This is a spoiler in a list. You can't see the number unless you hover the spoiler.
2. Numbering continues as expected.
3. > The issue can be reproduced multiple times in a single list.

   It even holds when a list item consists of multiple paragraphs.

**Unordered lists.**

- The issue holds in unordered lists as well.
- > This can be seen here.
- The number/bullet is not hidden when the spoiler is not the first part of the list item.

  > See?

Comment: [No-repro for me on Firefox, macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeMSV.png) but I do have an issue with Edge.

Comment: Many users have *an* issue with Edge @Glorfindel

Comment: Repro-ed in Chrome/ Win10

Comment: Yeah, that wording was deliberately chosen.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Edge 41.

Comment: Works fine in the iOS app. (Bullets are visible) doesn't work properly in safari for iOS, though.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug in WebKit / Blink - they're applying the child selector for the first child of the list element (`.spoiler:not(:hover)>*`) to the list marker.

Note that if the spoiler isn't the *first* child of the list item, this doesn't happen:

- one
- B

  > spoilerly spoiler
- 3

Comment: If you can reproduce it in Safari, it's in WebKit.

Comment: I don't have Safari, but from the comments it appears there too?

Comment: I'm a Windows/Android fan, and don't have access to an Apple device to test it on. Otherwise, I'd tell.

Comment: I'd file a bug on Google's issue tracker, since the bug *does* exist in Blink. Link me to the relevant issue if you do.